# What is an MvcHtmlString and when should I use it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring%28VS.100%29.aspx) for `MvcHtmlString` is not terribly enlightening:

> Represents an HTML-encoded string that should not be encoded again.

It's not clear to me what exactly the implications of this are. It seems that some HTML helper methods return an `MvcHtmlString`, but several examples I've seen online of custom helpers just return a regular string.

**Questions:**

What is an `MvcHtmlString`?

When should I choose `MvcHtmlString` over `string` and vice versa? Why?

Comment: I vote for link of document :D it's good for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 249, accepted):

ASP.NET 4 introduces a new code nugget syntax `<%: %>`.  Essentially, `<%: foo %>` translates to `<%= HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(foo) %>`.  The team is trying to get developers to use `<%: %>` instead of `<%= %>` wherever possible to prevent XSS.

However, this introduces the problem that if a code nugget already encodes its result, the `<%: %>` syntax will *re-encode* it.  This is solved by the introduction of the IHtmlString interface (new in .NET 4).  If the *foo()* in `<%: foo() %>` returns an IHtmlString, the `<%: %>` syntax will not re-encode it.

MVC 2's helpers return MvcHtmlString, which on ASP.NET 4 implements the interface IHtmlString.  Therefore when developers use `<%: Html.*() %>` in ASP.NET 4, the result won't be double-encoded.

**Edit:**

An immediate benefit of this new syntax is that your views are a little cleaner.  For example, you can write `<%: ViewData["anything"] %>` instead of `<%= Html.Encode(ViewData["anything"]) %>`.

Comment: I'd add that MVC 2 is compiled against .Net 3.5, not 4. This means that `MvcHtmlString` doesn't implement `IHtmlString` because that only exists in 4. The `<%:` syntax must _duck-type_ - it will always call `.ToHtmlString()` before `.ToString()` regardless of interface.

Comment: I stand corrected - actually the `MvcHtmlString.Create` method detects whether `IHtmlString` is available and dynamically creates the returned class to support it if it is: http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/net-framework/Encoding-and-Strings/3.aspx

Comment: **Follow Up:** Is there a meaningful difference between MvcHtmlString and HtmlString? After reading the docs linked above, I still did not know what MvcHtmlString gives me that HtmlString does not.

Comment: @flipdoubt - There is no meaningful difference.

Comment: There is one very slight difference between the two. MvcHtmlString will return String.Empty in ToString() or ToHtmlString() if you pass it a null string. HtmlString will continue to return null, though.

Answer (score 93):

This is a late answer but if anyone reading this question is using razor, what you should remember is that razor encodes everything by default, **but by using `MvcHtmlString` in your html helpers you can tell razor that it doesn't need to encode it**.

If you want razor to not encode a string use

```
@Html.Raw("<span>hi</span>")
```

Decompiling Raw(), shows us that it's wrapping the string in a HtmlString

```
public IHtmlString Raw(string value) {
    return new HtmlString(value); 
}
```

"*HtmlString only exists in ASP.NET 4.*

*MvcHtmlString was a compatibility shim added to MVC 2 to support both .NET 3.5 and .NET 4. Now that MVC 3 is .NET 4 only, it's a fairly trivial subclass of HtmlString presumably for MVC 2->3 for source compatibility.*"
[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382860/htmlstring-vs-mvchtmlstring)

Answer (score 11):

A nice practical use of this is if you want to make your own `HtmlHelper` extensions.  For example, I hate trying to remember the `<link>` tag syntax, so I've created my own extension method to make a `<link>` tag:

```
<Extension()> _
Public Function CssBlock(ByVal html As HtmlHelper, ByVal src As String, ByVal Optional ByVal htmlAttributes As Object = Nothing) As MvcHtmlString
    Dim tag = New TagBuilder("link")
    tag.MergeAttribute("type", "text/css")
    tag.MergeAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
    tag.MergeAttribute("href", src)
    tag.MergeAttributes(New RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes))
    Dim result = tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal)
    Return MvcHtmlString.Create(result)
End Function
```

I could have returned `String` from this method, but if I had the following would break:

`<%: Html.CssBlock(Url.Content("~/sytles/mysite.css")) %>`

With `MvcHtmlString`, using either `<%: ... %>` or `<%= ... %>` will both work correctly.

Answer (score 9):

You would use an `MvcHtmlString` if you want to pass raw HTML to an MVC helper method and you don't want the helper method to encode the HTML.

Comment: Hmm...I thought the whole point of an HTML helper method was to encode HTML. What would I do otherwise with an HTML helper method?

Comment: And, besides that, when would I want to *return* an `MvcHtmlString` from an HTML helper method?

Comment: Pass to or return from.  You would want to return one if your HTML helper generates pre-escaped HTML and you don't want anyone else re-escaping it.

Comment: Okay, I think that gets me a little bit closer, but (at the risk of coming across as a smart ass) how do I decide whether I want anyone else re-escaping it? Is it generally good/bad practice to give someone the ability to mess with escaped html? I've never seen a construct like this before. "It's like a string, but please don't touch it...not that there's anything preventing you from touching it, but we'd prefer you don't." What is that about?

Comment: The point is that unlike a regular string, _this_ string has already been encoded.  Therefore, there's no need to touch it.