# Passing NewLine (or <Br />) inside ViewData["msg"]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, newline, viewdata

How do I pass an `Environment.NewLine` (or a `< br />`) inside a `ViewData["msg"]`
that renders as a real `<br />` inside the View itself?

I'm using C# ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply use

```
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("<br />");
```

Have a [look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h(v=VS.100).aspx) for further details.

**EDIT**:

I am sorry but I did not understand the question at the beginning. I thought you wanted to encode the passed string. Sometimes I read question too fast :)

Anyway to completely answer your question have a look at these samples. Suppose in your action you have:

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult Index() {
    ViewData["Message"] = "This is a test." + "<br />" + "Does it work?";
    return View();
}
```

And in your view you have

```
<p>Sample 1: <br /><%= ViewData["Message"]%></p>
<p>Sample 2: <br /><%: ViewData["Message"]%></p>
```

Notice the difference between the two construct. You will get the following results:

```
Sample 1: 
This is a test.
Does it work?

Sample 2: 
This is a test.<br />Does it work?
```

So the first sample usage answer your question. The key is to simply not encoding the string as opposed to what I understood at the beginning. The second construct, the one that use `<%: %>`, available if you're using .NET 4.0, *automatically* encode every string it render.

If you still want to use this latest construct and avoid that the string would be encoded you have to use a trick. Simply tell the construct that the string is already encoded and it does not need to be re-encoded. To achieve this use this sample code

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult Index() {
    ViewData["Message2"] = MvcHtmlString.Create( "This is a test." + "<br />" + "Does it work?" );
    return View();
}
```

and in the view normally use the `<%: %>` construct

```
<p>Sample 3: <br /><%: ViewData["Message2"]%></p>
```

For more details on using the MvcHtmlString and how it works please refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293357/what-is-an-mvchtmlstring-and-when-should-i-use-it) on SO.

Ciao!

Comment: This was one of the first thing I did tried but never worked.

ViewData["Message"] = "This is a test." + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("<br />") + "Does it work?";

displays >> This is a test.&lt;br&gt;Does it work?

Even if I add HttpUtility.HtmlDecode on the View that displays the actual message and I get >> This is a test.<br />Does it work? 

...hummm

Comment: Grazie Lorenzo ...that worked perfectly !!!

BTW, 
this works well with <BR/> but NOT with \r\n

Answer (score 0):

Did you try \n or \r inside the ViewData string itself?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
TempData["MsgString"] = MvcHtmlString.Create("No Data" + "<br />" + "For Something");
```

Or, with variables:

```
TempData["MsgString"] = MvcHtmlString.Create(Strings.StrNoData + "<br />" + Strings.StrSomething);
```