# With the new Razor View Engine, should my HtmlHelpers return string or IHtmlString?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-encode

With the Razor View Engine, anytime you output a string directly to the page, it's HTML encoded. e.g.:

```
@"<p>Hello World</p>"
```

will actually get output to the page as:

```
&lt;p&gt;Hello World &lt;/p&gt;
```

Which would show up in the browser as:

<p>Hello World </p>

Here's the problem though, when creating Html helpers, till now, with the old aspx view engine I would just return a string, and output that to the browser:

```
<%= Html.MyCoolHelperMethod(); %>
```

So my question is basically this. Do I do this:

```
public static IHtmlString MyCoolHelperMethod(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
   return new helper.Raw("<p>Hello World</p>");
}
```

in which case I can just do this in my cshtml:

```
@Html.MyCoolHelperMethod();
```

or do I do this:

```
public static string MyCoolHelperMethod(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
   return "<p>Hello World</p>";
}
```

in which case I need to do the work in my cshtml:

```
@Html.Raw(Html.MyCoolHelperMethod());
```

Obviously the first approach makes the view look a lot cleaner, but I'm just wondering if the common pattern is in fact for helpers to return an `IHtmlString` and I've been doing it wrong in the past.

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293357/what-is-an-mvchtmlstring-and-when-should-i-use-it You should return IHtmlString

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In most cases you should return an instance of `IHtmlString`. That's the pattern followed by the built-in helpers* and it means that the consumer of a helper does not need to worry about under- or over-encoding.

Instead of using the `Raw` function you should probably just return a new instance of `HtmlString`.

```
public static IHtmlString MyCoolHelperMethod(this HtmlHelper helper) {
    return new HtmlString("<p>Hello World</p>");
}
```

*Note that MVC 3 actually uses `MvcHtmlString` as the return type of its helpers but this is a holdover from the MVC 2 days. (Complicated story, but in short, `IHtmlString` was only introduced in .NET 4 and since MVC 2 supported .NET 3.5 the `MvcHtmlString` type was introduced as an intermediate step). All helpers targetting MVC 3 and higher should return `IHtmlString`.

Comment: "All helpers targetting MVC 3 and higher should return IHtmlString." - just what I needed to know!