# Default encoder in HttpRuntime doesn't work for ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-encode, antixsslibrary, httpruntime

I'm making and setting `AntiXssEncoder` for my web project which uses mvc3 and .net4, and I've done these steps:

- add `AxtiXSSLibrary` reference
- create `AntiXSSEncoder` derived from `HttpEncoder`
- override the `HtmlEncode` method: `output.Write(Encoder.HtmlEncode(value));`
- set `encoderType` in `web.config` to `<httpRuntime encoderType="AntiXSSEncoder, MyDll"/>`

But I still can see the alert popup by xss input (`XssTest<script>alert("test");</script>`).

So I tested and found out the default encoder doesn't encode values which are assigned to `ViewBag`. My test code is below and it shows one isn't encoded.

```cs
//In controller code
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult AntiXss(string TextArea)
{
    ViewBag.DisplayInput = TextArea;
    ViewBag.DisplayEncodedInput = Encoder.HtmlEncode(TextArea);

    return View();
}
```

```
//In view code
@using (Html.BeginForm("AntiXss", "Test"))
{
    @Html.TextArea("TextArea")
    <p/>
    @Html.Raw(ViewBag.DisplayInput)
    <p/>
    @Html.Raw(ViewBag.DisplayEncodedInput)
    //@ViewBag.DisplayInput
    <p/>
    <input type="submit" value="ok"/>
}
```

```html
//In redered page code
<textarea id="TextArea" name="TextArea">&#13;&#10;XssTest&lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;Test&quot;);&lt;/script&gt;</textarea>    <p/>
XssTest<script>alert("Test");</script>    <p/>
XssTest&lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;Test&quot;);&lt;/script&gt;    <p/>
```

Can any one give me an answer or clue?

Comment: You are calling `@Html.Raw` which is supposed to not encode ths string. Why do you need a custom encoder in the first place? Everything output by Razor is encoded, unless passed to `@Html.Raw`. You could simply write `@ViewBag.DisplayInput` in the view and that would be encoded without any custom encoders.

Comment: Well, even though calling @Html.Raw, the 'DisplayEncodedInput' works exact what I expect. I don't think that's the problem. And I just want to allow html input to users and make application safe from xss. Thanks anyway.

Comment: `DisplayEncodedInput` works because you manually encode the value if the controller, then `Raw` displays it without additional actions. With Razor you simply output the user input, this is how it is designed. It is safe unless you pass it to the unsafe `Html.Raw` (and funnily, you are trying to use `Raw` to make it safe). See yourself - remove your custom encoder and replace calls to `@Html.Raw` with `@ViewBag.DisplayInput` and `@ViewBag.DisplayEncodedInput`.

Comment: You are right. I manually encoded the value, but that's the point why I'm trying to use my encoder instead of default encoder!!! I assumed that registering my encoder as default encoder would help me to encode every html before it's rendered, so I wouldn't need to encode manually. However it isn't working as I expected, so I'm asking how to do it.

Comment: Every HTML is encoded before it is rendered unless you pass it to `Html.Raw`. You pass it to `Html.Raw` so it is not encoded. You do not need a custom encoder to make this work. However if you do provide a custom encoder, even though you don't need to, `Html.Raw` will still not use it.

Comment: Oh! Doesn't `Html.Raw` use encoder? Doesn't it decode values which are encoded once?

Comment: No it does not decode and it does not care what the string contains. It creates an `MvcHtmlString` and puts the provided string in it. The MVC engine [knows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2293357/11683) that `MvcHtmlString` does not need further encoding for output.