# "Razor encodes everything by default"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've read [What is an MvcHtmlString and when should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293357/what-is-an-mvchtmlstring-and-when-should-i-use-it)
I did not understand the whole answer of Torbjörn Nomell. He wrote that "razor encodes everything by default." What does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He means that Razor will HTML-encode special characters. e.g.:

```
@{
    var test = "<br>";
}

@test
```

Will yield:

```
&lt;br&gt;
```

If you want to write out the raw HTML (e.g. you are trying to render rich text with HTML formatting) you need to use `Html.Raw`:

```
@Html.Raw(test);
```

Yields:

```
<br>
```