# Razor, StringBuilder, HTML line break?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a problem that is just making me feel silly.... Given the following code in Razor:

```
@{
    ...
    if (purchasedEvent.Address != null && purchasedEvent.Address != String.Empty){
        addressBlock.AppendFormat("{0}<br />", purchasedEvent.Address); 
    }
    ...
}
@addressBlock.ToString()
```

The `<br />` gets treated as literal text (that is to say I end up seeing something like `123 Cool Street<br />Anytown...` rendered on the page. Changing the code (back) to `addressBlock.AppendLine(purchasedEvent.Address)` doesn't do any good either (renders `127 Cool Street Anytown...`. What do I need to do to make the Razor engine respect that line break?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an MvcHtmlString and when should I use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293357/what-is-an-mvchtmlstring-and-when-should-i-use-it)

Comment: I think the second answer on that does indeed answer this question but I'm not sure the question directly translates even though it is a far more expanded way of asking it. Thanks for the link. Think maybe I should take this one down?

Comment: I actually wouldn't.  Duplicate questions worded differently are helpful for people trying to find an answer.  Closed questions are not automatically deleted by the system.

Comment: Honestly, that's what I was thinking/hoping but I'm not as familiar with SO protocol as others. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`Html.Raw`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx). To quote the docs: "Returns markup that is not HTML encoded."

So something like

```
@html.Raw(addressBlock.ToString())
```

The reason for it is that MVC is assuming that what you are giving it is the text as you want it to be seen and thus HTML encodes it. `Raw` allows you to tell it not to do that.

Comment: Yup, that did it. I knew it was something simple. Thank you.