# Extending HtmlHelper class asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem  with extending the HtmlHelper class to render an image tag

I just wrote this code

```
namespace Mace_CrmSystem
{
    public static class ExtendedHelper
    {
        public static TagBuilder HaidarImage(this HtmlHelper instance, string src) {
            TagBuilder inst = new TagBuilder("img");
            inst.MergeAttribute("src", src);
            return inst;     
        }
    }
}
```

and in the index view I wrote  this code

```
@Html.HaidarImage("http://haidar.ws/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/ipaduse.jpg");
```

but the problem is that when the view render the tag , it does not render it as an Hrml tag, rather it renders it as a normal text so the result be like this

```
 <img src="http://haidar.ws/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/ipaduse.jpg"></img>;
```

another problem is that I tried to add the namespace inside the web.config page to be available over all the page but the intellisense does not show the extended method until I explicitly declare it at the view page itself.

so please could anyone help me to solve my problem.

Comment: Change the method to `public static MvcHtmlString HaidarImage(..)` and add `return MvcHtmlString.Create(inst.ToString());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return an `IHtmlString` from your HtmlHelper extension method so that the output is not HTML encoded, as it is HTML markup that should not be encoded again. For example

```
public static IHtmlString HaidarImage(this HtmlHelper instance, string src) 
{
    TagBuilder inst = new TagBuilder("img");
    inst.MergeAttribute("src", src);
    return new HtmlString(inst.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));   
}
```

To fix the method being available in all views, you need to add the namespace of the class to the web.config inside of the Views folder.

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot, that fixed my problem, but I found a lesson in pluralSight  which describes the extending using the TagBuilder  class and exactly the same as I wrote my code, so I do not know if that had been working in the previous version of the mvc before they released the new version of mvc .

Answer (score 2):

You have to return `IHtmlString` like this so that it is rendred as Html :

```
 public static IHtmlString HaidarImage(this HtmlHelper instance, string src) 
 {

    TagBuilder inst = new TagBuilder("img");
    inst.MergeAttribute("src", src);
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(inst.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));   
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you are returning `TagBuilder` from your method, you should be returning [MvcHtmlString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring(v=vs.118).aspx) instead, try this:-

```
public static MvcHtmlString HaidarImage(this HtmlHelper helper, string src)
{
    TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("img");
    tag.Attributes.Add("src", src);
    return new MvcHtmlString(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
}
```

Why do we need `MvcHtmlString`, you can read it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293357/what-is-an-mvchtmlstring-and-when-should-i-use-it).