# Load html to browser from string that reads from DB

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

am building a blog engine using razor/asp.net mvc and I have a text area in which user should enter mainly paragraphs, links and headings. Content of textarea is taken and stored as varchar in db. When I retrieve that content I store it in a string , say content.

When I send this to razor view and do something like @Model.content it simply prints it all as a text. Now is there a simple way to make this work (meaning treat is as html not string) or what would you do in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@Html.Raw()` like below. Hope this will solve your problem.

```
@Html.Raw((Model.content))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be returning an [`MvcHtmlString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring(v=vs.118).aspx) instance instead of `string` in your model.

See also this previous question and answers [what is an mvchtmlstring and when should i use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293357/what-is-an-mvchtmlstring-and-when-should-i-use-it).