# base64 image is not displayed in asp.net mvc view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, base64, png

I want to show an image from a resx file inside a razor view:

My.cshtml:

```
<div>
        @Model.ImageTag
</div
```

With this helper:

```
 public static string CreateImageHtmlTag(this Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            ImageFormat format = null;
            if (Equals(bitmap.RawFormat, ImageFormat.Png))
            {
                format = ImageFormat.Png;
            }
            else if (Equals(bitmap.RawFormat, ImageFormat.Jpeg))
            {
                format = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("This image type is not supported!");
            }

            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            bitmap.Save(stream, format);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());

            return $@"<img src='data:image/{format};base64,{base64}' />";
        }
```

That is shown in my browser:

```
"<img src='data:image/Png;base64,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
B4qXnRA+wcqPsANfYmKGwMB3kSeuNZzJIHyd7XKPuCiIipujGbaH1UCoRs/SMWLDmj/G56Blt1DxY2Byuu8QJNtlfGKMGngKwJo+yR5MJvNs/NoU2NWFErLIMgbB3WL3UObFg1wFhqV9uNUPSoODg6axxKwfXA1lrKiKAngnQe02fsEFH5bkDYFx51parBtlSSgvZESJQxae/Ij1+4tkd81w70PLlj+h0uG2gzG9uFpTtUST3dP8SQ8w2CoGoL28d8M2yX83RxcPqqazvdcUl6HQLtToFptm4COcjnZIAY+1ITT9xlIut+3kzQKlz+8GcsZtnKNc65mOGtxJgCNjw2/L5oA4adNJ/A1KVxtnxNdOaooivI/TJ7jyaaaFhoAAAAASUVORK5CYII=' />"
```

Why is the image not rendered instead just a string is inserted?

Comment: Could be that you should return `MvcHtmlString` not `string` from your helper. I'm not sure how Razor work with escaping in that case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to return a `MvcHtmlString` instead of `string`.

```
public MvcHtmlString(
     string value
)
```

Take a look here for more explanation : 
[What is an MvcHtmlString and when should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293357/what-is-an-mvchtmlstring-and-when-should-i-use-it)

Comment: you were the first with "MvcHtmlString", and it worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Change your cshtml from:

```
<div>
        @Model.ImageTag
</div>
```

to

```
<div>
        @Html.Raw(@Model.ImageTag)
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your base64 code is correct, it opens as an image if I decode it. Maybe the issue is with the extension (try to use data:image/png not Png, so lowercase).

Answer (score 0):

you return a string by default doesnt convert your html tag when it receive string.
Asp.net offer tag **Html.Raw(your string)** to help convert it.