# creating helper method returning encoded text

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have  created a html helper method like this

```
  public static class abcExtensions
  {
    public static string Label1(this HtmlHelper helper, string target, string text)
    {
        return String.Format("<label for='{0}'>{1}</label>", target, text);

    }
}
```

But wne I use it like

```
@Html.Label1(..)
```

it render encoded text like this

> <label for='aa'>qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq</label>

I dont want to use @Html.Raw

How can I render Html instead of encoded text?

Comment: Recommend you study the [source code](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/LabelExtensions.cs)

Comment: @StephenMuecke do you know if I want my helper to connect to model?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand your comment (the source code shows how to write an extension method)

Comment: for example @Html.TextBox(m=>m.username,...) here, I can connect the helper with model data. How can I do this for creating my own helper?

Comment: yes you can write your own html helpers, see : http://developmentpassion.blogspot.nl/2014/09/creating-custom-html-helper-extensions.html

Comment: see this post as well, where we create image link :http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2015/07/image-actionlink-html-helper-in-aspnet.html

Comment: If you look at the source code it will show how to do that. But what are you trying to differently than the inbuilt `Label()` or `LabelFor()` methods?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I want something like @Html.Label1(m=>m.EmployeeName). and My rendered label gets filled with employee name because of m.EmployeeName. How can I do this?

Comment: @Alex, That does not make sense. A `<label>` element is associated with a form control (clicking on it sets focus to the control). Its the associated textbox that would be _filled with employee name_, not the label

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am just asking for learning purpose. lets call it label1For that I am creating. how to do this?

Comment: Your now asking a different question :) (and Ehsan Sajjad has answered this one correctly) . But I will give you a couple of links later.

Comment: @StephenMuecke ok thanks but please dont forget to give me the links later

Comment: @StephenMuecke also the mvc resource link you sent me above, can you send me labelExtension class link too on the same resource, later is ok?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117196/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-alex).

Comment: @EhsanSajjad you know the information the link you posted is not detailed enough. After reading it I have no idea what is:ControllerBase ControllerContext,ControllerDescriptor, or ActionDescriptor? Please explain the aboove classes

Comment: @Alex you can read the source code of those classes if you want to dive more deeper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return [`IHtmlString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihtmlstring(v=vs.110).aspx) which returns Html-Encoded string like;

```
public static IHtmlString Label1(this HtmlHelper helper, string target, string text)
{

   return new HtmlString(String.Format("<label for='{0}'>{1}</label>", target, text));

}
```

`HtmlString` wraps a string that is assumed to not need HTML encoded.It implements `IHtmlString`, so when calling `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(htmlString)` the string won't be encoded.

You can see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293357/what-is-an-mvchtmlstring-and-when-should-i-use-it) as well which explains more when should you use `HtmlString` which says that:

> what you should remember is that razor encodes everything by default, but by using MvcHtmlString in your html helpers you can tell razor that it doesn't need to encode it

You can always see [the source code](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/xsp/System/Web/HtmlString@cs/1305376/HtmlString@cs)  as well if you are interested to see how it works.

Comment: little explanation about IHtmlString?

Answer (score 0):

Make your helper method to return an HtmlString instead of string.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.htmlstring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: example how to do it?